# React-native Redux issue with Asynchronous functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Recently i have change the structure of my react-native app to use Redux, after that all my asynchronous functions have stopped work. I cant use AsyncStorage or take a picture with react-native-camera takePictureAsync. When i debug the code every time i use an await looks like the function is skipped and nothing is returned not even a error. I'm using an middleware ReduxThunk.

Example: This Action is used to take a picture, i'm using react-native-camera component. The issue here is the then and catch is not trigged and yes the function is been called, i can see it on debug

```
export const takePicture = (camera, options) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        camera.takePictureAsync(options)
        .then(data => {
            getPictureSuccess(data, dispatch);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            getPictureError(error, dispatch)
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you post your component, action and reducer? In Redux, async calls are typically done using side-effect libraries (Thunk or Saga), if you're using one of these, post that code as well.

Comment: Did you make the function `takePictureAsync`? What you are describing means the promise is never returned.

Comment: As @NorianNyx suggested, please add your file where you wired up `ReduxThunk` middleware as well.